# Load files out from ROOT

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanna create a folder, out of my ROOT dir. Called: 'karaoke'.

My ROOT dir is '/var/www/'.

If i try to load an .mp3 file from this 'karaoke' dir, it cannot find that.

I tried the following codes:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function(){ startFlash('','../karaoke/sample.mp3',''); });
</script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function(){ startFlash('','/var/karaoke/sample.mp3',''); });
</script>
```

If the 'karaoke' dir is in the ROOT dir, the following code works:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function(){ startFlash('','karaoke/sample.mp3',''); });
</script>
```

I dont understand this situation. If anyone can help, pls write a solution.

Thank, KoLi

Comment: Where is the kayaoke dir in the first example? what is the location of the file containing the above script?

Comment: In first example the karaoke dir is in '/var/'. So not in the ROOT dir. And the script is in index.php in '/var/www/'

Comment: Try with absolute path , `'/var/karaoke/sample.mp3'`

Comment: @KoLi there are TWO "roots"... the system root (/)  and the apache-defined web root (var/www).

Comment: Yes you'r right. I created this dir out of web root. I tried with absolute path in the first example, it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what the root is for!  If any client could simply use `../` notation to break out of your web root, they could call `../../../etc/shadow` or `../../apps/secretdatabase` or whatever else.

If you want your apache server to be able to serve a directory outside the root, use an `alias`:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

> The Alias directive allows documents to be stored in the local
>   filesystem other than under the DocumentRoot. URLs with a (%-decoded)
>   path beginning with URL-path will be mapped to local files beginning
>   with directory-path. The URL-path is case-sensitive, even on
>   case-insensitive file systems.
>
> ```
> Alias "/image" "/ftp/pub/image"
> ```

In your case, this would be like:

`Alias "/karaoke" "/var/karaoke"`